# Autolayout: Relative but changeable/animatable constraints?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uiviewanimation, nslayoutconstraint

Is there a recommended pattern for constraints which have relative values you expect to change frequently?

Here's the scenario: I have a slider-like control where I'm positioning the thumb view relative to the width of its parent view.  I can easily create a relative constraint for this:  constrain the child view to the opposite edge of its parent view, and set its relative position using the multiplier.

The problem is that the thumb view needs to move:  Its relative position needs to change when the user slides it.  If it were possible to change the multiplier dynamically, that would be the solution.  But, `NSLayoutConstraint.multiplier` is a read-only property!

Another way to do this is to set the `.constant` value to an explicit value relative to the width of the parent.  But this breaks down if the size of the parent view changes -- it's tricky to catch changes to the view width at the proper point in the update cycle to update the constraint.

Is there a better way to do this?  Seems like it should be possible, but I haven't quite conceptualized the Apple Way of thinking about it...

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Its relative position needs to change when the user slides it.

Then change its position, in the normal way (by changing the view's frame/center), as the user drags. That is *how* you implement a draggable view: you keep changing its frame/center as the user performs a touch gesture. This works perfectly well; the fact that you may have constraints positioning this "thumb" view is irrelevant.

A problem arises only if *layout* occurs; at that point, if you have auto layout constraints, they will take over. If they don't match the thumb's current position, it will jump back to its old position. You don't want that! So you have two easy possibilities:

- Don't use constraints to position/size this "thumb". Not every view in a hierarchy has to use auto layout.
- If you do use constraints to position/size the "thumb" (and I can see why you might want to), then *after* the user has moved the thumb (which really means you've changed its "thumb" position by setting its frame/center, as I already said), replace its positional constraints with new ones matching its new position.

Think, in other words, of constraints as merely what they are, a coded set of instructions for setting a view's frame/center at layout time. They can and should be treated nimbly. A view can be removed from the influence of auto layout, manipulated directly, and then returned to that influence. Or the influence of auto layout can even be momentarily ignored, as it makes no difference and has no effect until the special moment of layout comes along. In other words, don't let yourself be constrained by your own constraints!

Comment: Right -- I could implement this without autolayout.  But, the point is I *want* to use autolayout.  I've found that mixing autolayout and non-autolayout approaches in the same code gets tricky pretty fast.  I could repeatedly delete and recreate the position constraint when the thumb moves, but I suspect that would get glitchy in some circumstances;  I think constraints are only intended to be created once. Any thoughts on a pure autolayout approach? :)

Comment: You've had success swapping constraints on an interactive, rapidly moving view *as it's moving*? I'm skeptical about that approach.  Setting up constraints has overhead; I don't think it's something you want to do in a tight loop.

Comment: Yes, I read your answer.  To clarify, I'm looking for a pure autolayout approach.